# for vs foreach - reference to array elements

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I had an array which contained lines of a file that I had to process, each element of the array was a line of the file. After processing I implode the file, write it out and use it.

When I tried to use `foreach` for this, it didn't work. I had a suspicion that it was creating a copy of the element rather than referencing the element directly, so used a `for` loop instead, which did work.

My question is, is there some way to use a `foreach` loop in this scenario or when redefining elements of an array must you always use a `for` loop?

Example code:

```
$fileArray = file('blah.txt');
foreach ($fileArray as $thisLine) {
    if ( condition ) {
        $thisLine = "changed state";
    }
}
$newFileArray = implode('',$fileArray);
```

Didn't work vs:

```
$fileArray = file('blah.txt');
for ($x=0;$x<count($fileArray);$x++) {
    if ( condition ) {
        $fileArray[$x] = "changed state";
    }
}
$newFileArray = implode('',$fileArray);
```

Which worked fine.

Comment: You can use foreach, but if you wish to reference use & infront of variable. In your example `foreach ($fileArray as &$fileLine) {`

Comment: Never forget to UNSET this reference directly after the foreach loop, otherwise you will wreck heavoc on your data: `unset($fileLine)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fileArray = file('blah.txt');
foreach ($fileArray as $key => $thisLine) {
    if ( condition ) {
        $fileArray[$key] = "changed state";
    }
}
$newFileArray = implode('',$fileArray);
```

or passing by reference directly:

```
$fileArray = file('blah.txt');
foreach ($fileArray as &$thisLine) {
    if ( condition ) {
        $thisLine = "changed state";
    }
}
$newFileArray = implode('',$fileArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're altering a copy of a string.  `$thisLine` is not a reference to the element in the array, but a copy of the array element.

In your second example, you are altering the array directly.  You could use a foreach, but only if you go back to referencing the array:

```
foreach ($fileArray as $key => $thisLine) {
    if ( condition ) {
        $fileArray[$key] = "changed state";
    }
}
```